# How to test if GATT server connection shut down

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I have an app hosted no my phone which connects to a GATT server hosted on a BLE device. Here is how I connect my app to the BLE device.

```
BlueTootGatt mGatt = new bleDevice.connectGatt(context, false, callback);
```

Now that I have a gatt server object, I cant write and read data to it using its services.

Now say one of three possible things can happen

- My phone goes out of range
- I disable my bluetooth
- The BLE device is shut down

How can I test if the gatt connection has been shutdown in one of these arbitrary ways? Like for example, some method that returns a boolean would be nice

```
mGatt.disconnected(); // returns true or false
```